# How to make $elemMatch work for json array data in mango query?

Tags: couchdb

I have a field in my application like below.

```
{
 "Ct": "HH",
  Val:{
   "Count":"A",
   "Branch":"A"
  }
 }
```

When I'm trying to retrieve this using below command in CouchDB, I'm unable to retrieve records.

```
{
 "selector" : {
    "Val":{
      "$elemMatch":{
         "Count":"A"
       }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the CouchDB documentation,`$elemMatch`<sup>[1]</sup>

> Matches and returns all documents that contain an array field with at
> least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

`Val.Count` is not an array field so `$elemMatch` is not appropriate.

Consider the CouchDB documentation regarding subfield queries<sup>[2]</sup>:

> **1.3.6.1.3. Subfields**
>
> A more complex selector enables you to specify the values for field of
> nested objects, or subfields. For example, you might use a standard
> JSON structure for specifying a field and subfield.
>
> Example of a field and subfield selector, using a standard JSON
> structure:
>
> ```
> {
>     "imdb": {
>         "rating": 8
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> An abbreviated equivalent uses a dot notation to combine the field and
> subfield names into a single name.
>
> ```
> {
>     "imdb.rating": 8
> }
> ```

Specifically,

```
selector: {
   "Val.Count": "A"       
}
```

<sup>1</sup> [CouchDB: 1.3.6.1.7. Combination Operators](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#combination-operators) 
<sup>2</sup> [CouchDB: 1.3.6.1.3. Subfields](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#subfields)

Comment: Thank you for the help